# Why is this port scanner written in node don't give accurate results?

Tags: node.js

I have written this port-scanner but it is not giving me accurate results. Here are my observations about this scanner

- On different runnings, it may give you different res
- I noticed that on shrinking the range of ports results get better

Here is the code:

```js
const net = require('net')

function findPortStatus(port, host, timeout) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const socket = net.createConnection(port, host, () => {
      resolve(port)
      socket.destroy()
    })

    socket.setTimeout(timeout, () => {
      resolve('timeout')
      socket.destroy()
    })

    socket.on('error', (err) => {
      resolve('error')
    })
  })
}


const promises = []

for (let port = 1; port <= 65535; port++) {
  promises.push(findPortStatus(port, process.argv[2], 10000))
}

Promise.all(promises)
  .then(ports => {
    for (let port of ports) {
      if (typeof(port) === 'number') {
        console.log(port)
      }
    }
  })
```

Please try by changing the range manually from the code and running the code multiple times. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To run this code, you'll need a lot of resources... like 64k sockets open at the same time, 64k file descriptors, etc.

I think you should check what kind of errors you have: limited file descriptors may be the culprit.

Then maybe you should spread the load, using `async.queue` for instance instead of `Promise.all` (eg. test 200 ports at once, not more)... Promises are not ideal for this use case, because they start ASAP when they're created. `Promise.all` just waits until completion, it doesn't actually start the work.

Latency will increase, but resource usage will be more manageable. Attempting to hit all 64k ports at once is a lot of load...